# Starting new Screen on the background on reboot

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I have telegram-bot, which I would like to get running every reboot automatically. I've been using Screen to detach this python script manually and leaving it to the background. Before, I have used Screen's commands `Ctrl+A` and D to detach the session.

I've tried to learn some Screen commands, but it doesnt seem to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
cd "/home/mainuser/Documents/TelegramBot";
sleep 5
python3 telegram_bot.py
```

And I have set this as command.sh in Documents/LaunchCommands. Then, in my crontab I have:

```
@reboot screen -S TELEGRAM -X screen /home/mainuser/Documents/LaunchCommands/command.sh
```

But when I restart my computer, nothing is running. Any help on what might be wrong?? I would love to have the Screen, open new session with name: "TELEGRAM", launch that script in that session and then detach it to the background, so that I can re-attach later if I want. Any ideas? Thank you for your help!

You can also suggest some other ideas, how to get this python script running at the background in a way, that I can still interact with it.

Comment: I don't know why you use `screen` for this

Comment: first try to run in `cronjob` script which write some data in text file to see if it really works. ie. `date >> /home/mainuser/output.txt'` Script in `crontab may need to use /full/path/to/script` and `/full/path/to/python'

Comment: Hi! I used the cronjob-script and it is working fine. And as for @furas, I need to use Screen or similar to leave the script running at the background. It is waiting for someone to send a message for the Telegram bot, and then it will respond to that.

Comment: you don't need `screen` to run something in background. You may need `sreen` when you connect to server using `ssh` and run code manually and you want to exist `ssh` (which close all started program) - and then `screen` keep running session. But when you run it with `crontab` then you don't need to keep running session - it doesn't close `ssh` connection.

Comment: @furas, Yes! This is the point that I try to do. It would be nice for me to start something on reboot, when when I log in to my server over SSH, I can take a loot at that process and leave it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after looong time debugging, and asking from elsewhere, here's how I got this working:

In crontab, I have line:

```
@reboot sleep 5; /usr/bin/screen -dmS TELEGRAM /home/mainuser/Documents/LaunchCommands/command.sh &
```

And my command.sh is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo
cd "/home/mainuser/Documents/TelegramBot";
python3 telegram_bot.py
```

And now everything works like a charm!